# How to disable the popup that appears for input validation ("Please fill out this field")?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, angular

I am using Angular 2 and I have a form with input as follows (simplified for readability's sake):

```
<input class="body-text1" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" required minlength="1">
<!--more, similar inputs -->
```

I have my own angular validation, but the first input field gets a popup that is relevant to the input. For example, a plain text required input will receive a popup that says "Please fill out this field." while an input marked with `type=email` will say something like "Invalid email, must have @" (I forget the exact email popup text).

As far as I can tell, I did not add these popups in. I have tried adding `formnovalidate` / `novalidate` as attributes to the inputs based on a question that looked similar but it did not help.

Comment: Maybe remove `required` DOM property from your input-tag?

Answer (score 3):

You might need to add `novalidate` attribute to your form to prevent Browser default behaviour.

```
<form novalidate>
```

Comment: Best answer ever !!!

Answer (score 2):

This popup shows because the `required` attribute is on the element. If you remove this, the popup will be gone, so will the validation be though.